# Stockholm format to dot-brackets format?

Tags: bioinformatics, rna

I need to convert all my sequences in a Stockholm format into this:

```
hg19_11_6_Ala          ----------------.GG--gggaguggugu....gguuacgaaugUGGCCUCUGC-----AA.............................................................GCAGACA.........................G..CCUGGGUUCAAUU...........................
#=GR hg19_11_6_Ala  PP .................22..45677788888....899999999996777899988.....56.............................................................8999999.........................9..*************...........................
```

Into something like this:

```
 hg19_11_6_Ala         ................((..(((((((((((...)))))))))))))))))))))))....((................................)))))))))......)))).....................
```

Obviously, being coherent with the stockholm format. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to find a consensus structure for a group of alignments in stockholm format then you might try with 
[RNAalifold](http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at/cgi-bin/RNAalifold.cgi)
 and for single sequence folding check [RNAfold](http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at/cgi-bin/RNAfold.cgi). Both have online servers and can also be run offline.

After you get the consensus structure update the stockholm file by adding  a structure consensus line as: `#=GC SS_cons` followed by the dot bracket notation.

A nice RNA structure editor that will make your life easier is EMACS when complemented with [RALEE](http://sgjlab.org/ralee/). It allows you to view and manipulate RNA structures, predict structure folding and color the alignments based on basepairs relationships. It will be worth it to invest time into mastering RALEE.